# How to select characters between wildcards in Azure Data Factory expression for Switch Block

Tags: sql, switch-statement, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have 2 pipelines that are currently selected based on an IF condition, which works well.  I now need to add a third pipeline , so using a Switch block instead.  And instead of tablename as the deciding factor, ideally I would use logic something like this:

1. does the sourcetablename value contain {FromDate} then goto pipeline A
2. does the sourcetablename value contain {passinid} then goto pipeline B
3. else goto pipeline C

The sourcetablename value comes with the initial gettablestoload lookup.

An example sourcetablename value is used for the API call in this instance, and would look like this for example:  **blahblah/content/{passinid}/user/blahblah**

I am struggling with the expression for the switchblock.  Previously I have matched on the last 10 characters of the tablename, this just seems a little bit tricky.

Here is an example of an expression to remove the last 46 characters, just to give you an idea where I am struggling up to:

```
@substring(activity('GetTablesToLoad').SourceTableName,0,sub(length(activity('GetTablesToLoad').SourceTableName),46))
```

Would anyone have an idea please?

If this was SQL it would be something like this:

```
 DECLARE @text VARCHAR (500) = 'content/{passinid}/user'
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('{', @Text)
, CHARINDEX('}',@text) - CHARINDEX('{', @Text) + Len('}'))
```

[image: switchblock]

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` function to check for required value directly. I have taken a parameter called `sourceTableName` for demonstration instead of lookup value.

- I have used the following dynamic content as expression value for switch activity. You can replace the `pipeline().parameters.sourceTableName` with lookup activity SourceTableName value. The name of switch case cannot start with `{` so, I have directly taken the name.

```
@if(contains(pipeline().parameters.sourceTableName,'{passinid}'),'passinid',if(contains(pipeline().parameters.sourceTableName,'{FromDate}'),'FromDate','execute default'))
```

[image]

- When the parameter value is `blahblah/content/{passinid}/user/blahblah`, the corresponding `set variable3` is executed.

[image]

- When the parameter value is `blahblah/content/{FromDate}/user/blahblah`, the corresponding `set variable4` is executed.

[image]

- If these values are not present (`blahblah/conten/user/blahblah`), then the default case would be executed (set variable2 activity).

[image]

Comment: thankyou @SaideepArikontham for your comprehensive reply.  I am in NZ so will apply this tomorrow - certainly looks awesome.  Your illustrations are super helpful.

Comment: Used @if(contains(activity('GetTablesToLoad').output.value[0].SourceTableName,'{passinid}'),'passinid',if(contains(activity('GetTablesToLoad').output.value[0].SourceTableName,'{FromDate}'),'FromDate','execute default')) which works perfectly.